# Get LDAP to work without rebooting

Tags: services, ldap

I am trying to create an automatic/unattended install of Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop suing preseeding and puppet:

1. Install with preseed, include puppet and start puppet on reboot, preseed also changes greeter options as needed (this is working)
2. upon reboot, puppet will do its thing and install/config LDAP
3. However, I can still only login locally until I reboot

What service can I restart, or what do I need to do so that I can login with LDAP without having to reboot the computer?

Edit: I used these instruction to get the LDAP Authentication on clients:
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html#openldap-auth-config

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 16.04 `sudo systemctl restart slapd.service` should work.

Comment: I am using 16.04, but get:  slapd.service not found